# Merging "n" arrays?

Tags: php

I have a function that takes an array of directories as a parameter. I'm trying to merge this array so I can use it for comparison. How can I use `array_merge()` when I have a variable amount of arrays to add?

```
public function foo($items, $dirs = []) {
    $skus = file($items, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $list = [];

    foreach($dirs as $img) {
        array_push($list, scandir($img));
    }

    $foo = array_merge($list[0], $list[1]); // Don't know what to do here ..
}
```

Comment: Try `array_reduce` - repeatedly merge the arrays using an empty array as a base.

Comment: maybe `$list[0]` and `$list[1]` isn't arrays ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP supports sending an array as arguments to the function:

```
$foo = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $list);
```

That will pass `$list` elements to the `array_merge` function.

BTW, you might want to use `array_reduce`:

```
$foo = array_reduce($list, 'array_merge', []);
```

both methods give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best way but you can make multiple array_merge() :

```
$array = array();

for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count($list); $i++ )
    $array = array_merge($array, $list[$i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_merge php function: array array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )

http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what you have, add the most recent list to the $mergedArray. & passes by reference :

```
$mergedArray = array(); (somewhere in your code, heck its PHP you dont need to define this first but for the sake of clarity ....)
public function foo($items, $dirs = [], &$mergedArray) {
    $skus = file($items, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $list = [];

    foreach($dirs as $img) {
        array_push($list, scandir($img));
    }

    $mergedArray = array_merge($mergedArray, $list); 
}
```